# Issue with Java syntax on Junit, last line fails

Tags: java, junit

```
  CustomErrorDecoder customErrorDecoder = new CustomErrorDecoder();
    Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
    Mockito.when(response.status()).thenReturn(400);
    Assertions.assertEquals(BadRequestException.class,customErrorDecoder.decode("hdjhsdjs",response).getClass());

    Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException.class,() -> {
        customErrorDecoder.decode("hdjhsdjs",response);
   }
  );
```

The last line failed
with the following error:

```
    Expected uk.co.vw.exception.BadRequestException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected uk.co.vw.exception.BadRequestException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Comment: Could you please post the code of `CustomErrorDecoder.decode` method? According to your test, it seems to me that it RETURNS `BadRequestException` instead of THROWING it.

Comment: thanks, indeed. problem solved, thanks for quick response

Comment: @andrej Istomin you are an absolute star